# I can't get both my header and footer menus to display properly in my wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to make a header menu for my main hyperlinks and a footer menu for my social media icons.

I've had the header one for a while, but it's only since I've tried to add a menu in the footer that it's started displaying only the footer menu in the header and footer. I've ensured that all of the settings are correct in the wordpress back end, but I still can't get this to work.

In my header.php I have:

```
<nav class="header-nav">
<?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'header'); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

In my footer.php I have:

```
<nav class="footer-nav">
<?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'footer'); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>
```

And in the functions.php I have:

```
register_nav_menus(array( 
'header' => __( 'Header Menu'), 
'footer' => __( 'Footer Menu'),
));
```

Comment: You're not passing the `$args` to the function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change into functions.php :

```
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary Menu', 'theme_wp' ),    
            'header' => __( 'Menu Header' ),
            'footer' => __( 'Menu Footer' )
            /*'an-extra-menu' => __( 'An Extra Menu' ) */
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

Now into template :

**header.php**

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header' ) );

**footer.php**

wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer' ) );

Don´t forget asign menu into Options Wp --> https://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel

Comment: Thanks pio, it worked! Sorry if this sounds a little stupid, but I'm really not experienced with php – If I were trying to add a third menu, say, in the footer. Would I add wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'footer' ) );  and then add 'footer' => __( 'Menu Footer 2' ) ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but you must add the function register_my_menus function () and add the third menu in the footer.php ---> wp_nav_menu (array ('theme_location' => 'third-footer')); .